# Django - Making a SQL query on a many to many relationship with PostgreSQL Inner Join

Tags: sql, django, postgresql

I am looking for a perticular raw SQL query using Inner Join.

I have those models:

```
class EzMap(models.Model):
    layers = models.ManyToManyField(Shapefile, verbose_name='Layers to display', null=True, blank=True)


class Shapefile(models.Model):
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Feature(models.Model):
    shapefile = models.ForeignKey(Shapefile)
```

I would like to make a SQL Query valid with PostgreSQL that would be like this one:

```
select id from "table_feature" where' shapefile_ezmap_id = 1 ;
```

but I dont know how to use the `INNER JOIN` to filter `features` where the `shapefile` they belongs to are related to a particular `ezmap` object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```py
try:
    id = Feature.objects.get(shapefile__ezmap__id=1).id
except Feature.DoesNotExist:
    id = 0 # or some other action when no result is found
```

You will need to use `filter` (instead of `get`) if you want to deal with multiple `Feature` results.

Comment: thanks a lot. Using then QuerySet.query I could get the raw SQL query that I needed